# Upgrade Product for all SAAS Customers

Tags: amazon-web-services, software-update

We have a monolithic application deployed in Cloud. We have one instance & DB per customer. We have multiple customers on different versions of the Software.

Since it's a maintenance nightmare to maintain multiple versions we have decided to upgrade all customers to the same version in the future.

What is the best way to achieve this? What are the things to remember while upgrading?